# Using asp.net ImageResizer api

Tags: asp.net, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm using ImageResizer (imageresizing.net) and I'm able to create resized images:

```
public void DoMagic(string original)
{
    string newImage = Server.MapPath("~/Images/test.png");
    ResizeSettings setting = new ResizeSettings("width=100&height=200");
    ImageBuilder.Current.Build(original, newImage,  setting);
}
```

I cannot figure out how to use grayscale or brightness:

```
s.grayscale=true|y|ry|ntsc|bt709|flat (true, ntsc, and y produce identical results)

s.brightness= -1..1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just forgot to install the SimpleFilters plugin. After that just followed [this](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/simplefilters)
and then this

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(original, newImage, new ResizeSettings("width=100&height=200&crop=auto&s.grayscale=true"));
```